# A field with an element of order $12$: $(a+a^{-1})^2=3.$

Tags: field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field and $a\in K^*$ of order $12.$ I need to prove that $(a+a^{-1})^2=3.$

'Progress': I expand $(a+a^{-1})^2=a^2+a^{-2}+2$ so equivalently I need to prove that $a^2+a^{-2}=1$, or the inverse of $a^2$ is $1+a^{-4}.$ I tried also Binomial theorem and working with the inverse but no success.

Not sure how can I use the fact that the order of $a$ is $12$. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: The element $a$ must be a zero of the 12th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_{12}(x)=x^4-x^2+1$. Do you understand why?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen First time I hear this 'name', but if $a$ is of order $12$ then just writing $a^{12}-1=..$ and I get the cyclotomic polynomial, right ?

Comment: Yup. But you also know that $a^6-1\neq0$ and $a^4-1\neq0$. Well, looks like André wants to explain this...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah! Nice, I was focus on your comment, I will see André Nicolas's answer after. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $(a^6-1)(a^6+1)=0$. But $a^6\ne 1$, so $a^6+1=0$. Thus $(a^2+1)(a^4-a^2+1)=0$. Because the order of $a$ does not divide $4$, we have $a^4-a^2+1=0$. This is equivalent to what you want to show.