# Show if $a^{12} = e$ so $(a+a^{-1})^2 = 3$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $a \in \mathbb{K}^*$ such that $a^{12} = e$.
I have to show that $(a+a^{-1})^2 = 3$

Since $\mathbb{K}$ is a field so it is commutative and by binomial theorem and $aa^{-1} = e$

$$ (a + a^{-1})^2 = a^2 + 2e + (a^{-1})^2 $$

To get $(a + a^{-1})^2 =3 $ we have to show $a^2 + (a^{-1})^2 = e$ i .e. I have to find $ x \in \mathbb{K}^* $, $a^2 + (a^{-1})^2 = xx^{-1} = e$
To find such $x$, we have $a^{12} = e$ so $a^{-1} = a^{11}$ but I get
$$ a^2 + (a^{-1})^2 = a^2+a^{22} = a^2 + a^{12}a^{10} = a^2 + a^{10} $$
And I don't know how to get further..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ and $a=1$?

Comment: @Stephen If that so, $a^{-1} = 1$ and $(a+a^{-1})^2 = (1+1)^2 = 2^2 = 4 \neq 3$.. I tried to find an example too but it has to be a field with an element of order 12. ($\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is not a good candidate because $12$ is not prime so $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is not a field..)

Comment: @Stephen But $a^{12} = e$ so its order is 12 then $\langle a \rangle$ is a sub-group of $\mathbb{K}$. Since $\mathbb{K}$ is a field then $\langle a \rangle$ is a finite cyclic group of order 12. We got the quantity
$$ a^2 + a^{10} \in \langle a \rangle $$
So we have to find $k$ such that 
$$ a^2 + a^{10} = a^k $$
But to get $a^2 + a^{10} = e$ we have to show $k = 0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A field with an element of order $12$: $(a+a^{-1})^2=3.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521277/a-field-with-an-element-of-order-12-aa-12-3) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E%7B12%7D%3De%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24(a%2Ba%5E%7B-1%7D)%5E2%3D3%24&p=1). Your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802099/show-if-a12-e-so-aa-12-3#comment10212892_4802099) indicates that there's "an element of order $12$", so I assume that this proposed duplicate question is a match.

Comment: $a^{12} = e$ doesn't mean $a$ is of order 12.